# Powershell Remoting into Non-Domain server issue

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-domain, remote-connection

Can anyone help with the following problem?
I am trying to remote into a server (`SVR_A`) that is not part of the domain from the server (`SRV_B`) in a company domain.

- The IP address range of `SRV_B` is `10.0.X.X`.
- The IP address of `SRV_A` is `172.23.1.2`.

I can ping each server (`SVR_A` to `SVR_B` and vise versa). WinRM is running on both servers and `Enable-PSRemoting` is configured correctly in both cases. The `SRV_B` also has added the `SRV_A` to its `TrustedHosts` list.

```
get-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts
```

Returns

```
 WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

pe            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
--            ----                           -------------   -----
stem.String   TrustedHosts                                   SVR_A
```

The `SRV_A` is one of the web servers in our DMZ, so there are other web servers that are not part of domain. I can remote into web servers using `Invoke-Command` or `Enter-PSSession`, **but not from the App Server (`SRV_B`) which is in company domain.**

### I get this error

```
[SRV_A] Connecting to remote server SRV_A failed with the following error message : The client
cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and
is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination,
most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to
analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SRV_A:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken
```

#### Powershell Version on both end

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.19170
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

### Result of `winrm e winrm/config/listener` on `SRV_A`

```
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 172.23.1.2, ::1, fe80::5efe:172.23.1.2%13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. As per the `winrm e winrm/config/listener` output on Server `A`...**

- it is using port `5985`
- and listening with an IP address of `172.23.1.2`

**2. Check any firewall rules or router configurations and ensure...**

- the `10.0.x.x` Server `B` traffic can get across  to the `172.23.1.2` IP address (*and subnet*) to Server `A`
- and with the `5989` port in particular

**3. Additionally...**

- run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force;` PowerShell administrator elevated on Server `A` *again*
- consider trusting only the IP address of Server `B` or it's entire `10.0.x.x` subnet on Server `A`
- use  a valid Server `A` credential but execute it on Server `B` with the  remote PowerShell command and it will work with non-trusted domains as long as the network traffic and port access is allowed

  - > ### Executing this on Server B
    >
    > ```
    >  Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ServerA" -ScriptBlock { 
    >     <Remote Command...>
    >     } -Credential Get-Credential "SrvA\UserNameHere"
    > ```

**4. To assist troubleshooting...**

- run `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "ServerA" -Credential Get-Credential "SrvA\UserNameHere"` to confirm you can access Server `A` from Server `B`

**5. Last but not least for more thoroughness...**

- consider updating your Server 2012 R2 to [PowerShell 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) for additional thoroughness

---

#### Supporting Resource

- [How to configure WINRM for HTTPS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/system-management-components/configure-winrm-for-https)
- [Enable-PSRemoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Enter-PSSession](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Invoke-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1)