# Execute powershell script with different credentials

Tags: powershell, script, credentials

I am trying to write a script, which asks for credentials via the "Get-Credential" cmdlet
and then executes the logic part with the given credentials.

I know I could write a second script which then runs the main one but I think there must be a more convenient way.

Comment: i think we need a little bit more information here. also maybe an example of what you tried.

Comment: See [***3. Additionally*** section](https://superuser.com/questions/1617091/powershell-remoting-into-non-domain-server-issue/1617749#1617749)

Answer (score 0):

It heaveily depends on what your script is supposed to do and further requirements.

The cmdlets might already support using credentials. You might use [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1) to invoke a separate PowerShell that runs with said credentials. In that case you could use `-Command` to supply your script or one of the other options. You might also be able to just use [`Invoke-Command`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1). This does require `-ComputerName` if you use credentials and PS Remoting.

An easy example would be the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {$env:USERNAME}
```

Comment: @waldtobi Where `$env:USERNAME` is the code block you are running with that credential within the `-ScriptBlock { }` brackets. You can put the code on multiple lines within the brackets too. Just test and confirm and you'll be off. The system you remotely execute the process against may need run elevated `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`.... https://superuser.com/questions/1643795/psexec-with-get-winevent-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/1644255#1644255